# Find remaining string after deleting a substring repeately

Tags: c++, arrays, string, algorithm, search

Let S and T be given strings. Then we remove T from S at the first occurrence of T in S, and call the remaining string of S to be S1. Again, we remove T from S1 at the first occurrence of T in S1, and call the remaining string of S1 to be S2. Repeatly do so until there is no substring T in Sk.

Note that we may have a substring T in S after removing T. What is the remaining string of S? (It is fine if S is empty.)

Constraint:

- 1 <= length(S) <= 10^6.
- 1 <= length(T) <= 100.

For example, S = "aa**abba**b**abba**bab", T = "abba". The remaining string is "ab".

I'm thinking to use KMP to have a prefix on T. Then when we find a string T in S, we have to change the indices i and j (i for S, and j for T) to new locations. However, I'm not exactly sure what j (and probably i) should be? The string may have a lot of fragments.

Is my approach correct? If so, could you please give me detailed steps how I can do it, especially what would be the new value of j? I stuck at the value of j. I don't know what I should assign j to after finding a match. This is part of the algorithm which I couldn't figure out.

This is my uncompleted code.

```
std::vector<int> make_prefix(std::string &t) {
    std::vector<int> prefix(t.length());
    prefix[0] = 0;
    for (int i = 1, j = 0; i < t.length(); )
        if (t[i] == t[j]) {
            prefix[i] = j + 1;
            ++i; ++j;
        }
        else if (j > 0)
            j = prefix[j - 1];
        else
            prefix[i++] = 0;
    return prefix;
}

std::string repeatRemoving(std::string s, std::string t) {
    std::vector<int> prefix = make_prefix(t);
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < s.length(); ) {
        if (s[i] == t[j]) {
            ++i;
            ++j;
        }
        else if (j > 0)
            j = prefix[j - 1];
        else
            ++i;

        if (j == (int)t.length()) {
            // What should go here after finding a match?
            // How can I adjust the values of i and j?
            // How can I mark the deleted characters in s?
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Just as a hasty guess after reviewing KMP, I think the key will be remembering the start and length of previous partial matches, until they can be eliminated by finding a character which is not part of any ongoing match.

Comment: Can't you remove all of them using `regex_replace()`?

Comment: They may overlap, S = "abababccc", T="abc" -> "ababcc", incorrect with one pass of replace

Comment: @KennyOstrom Exactly what I'm thinking. However, I have trouble implementing that. It seems to be more complicated than what I thought. T may be split up into many pieces.

Comment: @Barmar As Kenny Ostrom said, a new string T may form after removing T.

Comment: Can't you just repeatedly do the replacements until the string isn't found?

Comment: @Barmar The running time can go up to O(n^2).

Comment: @Barnar That algorithm may not be correct. Removing every occurrence of `abcab` from `a abcab bc abcab` (ignoring whitespace, those are there for emphasis) gives `abc`, but always removing the leftmost occurrence gives first `a bc abcab` = `abcab cab`, then `cab`. So regex-replacing all occurrences repeatedly can give different results than replacing the first occurrence repeatedly. The latter can still be done with regex, though for efficiency you probably want some operations that most regex libraries do not expose (e.g. to let you roll back the current DFA state after the replacement).

Comment: I think the simplest thing will be to just store the value of `i` and `j` for each position in `S`, so that you can restore them when you find a match.

Comment: Can you please show me how to know the value of ``i`` to change ``j`` to that position? How do I know the start of the current T in S? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the code. I need 2 more arrays:

- `prev`: storing the previous positions of `i` indices on `S`. Initially `prev[i] = prev[i - 1]`. When we find a match at the `i + length(T)` position, we set `prev[i + length(T) + 1] = i - 1` (i.e We point `prev` of a new position `i` to skip the entire string `T`).
- `jv`: storing the value of `j` at each `i` position on `S`.

After deleting all `T` in `S`, we use `prev` to reconstruct the remaining string. The overall complexity is `O(n m)`.

Here is the whole code:

```
std::string remaining_after_delete_repeatedly(std::string s, std::string t) {
    std::vector<int> prefix = make_prefix(t);
    s += "#";
    std::vector<int> prev(s.length());
    std::vector<int> jv(s.length());

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); prev[i] = i - 1, ++i);

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < s.length(); ) {
        if (s[i] == t[j]) {
            jv[i] = j;
            ++i;
            ++j;
        }
        else if (j > 0)
            j = prefix[j - 1];
        else
            jv[i++] = 0;
        if (j == (int)t.length()) {
            int u = i - 1;
            for (int k = 0; k < t.length(); ++k)
                u = prev[u];
            prev[i] = u;
            j = u < 0 ? 0 : jv[u] + 1;
        }
    }
    std::string answer(1, s.back());
    for (int i = prev[s.length() - 1]; i > -1; i = prev[i])
        answer += s[i];
    std::reverse(answer.begin(), answer.end());
    return answer.substr(0, answer.length() - 1);
}
```